# copy binary file into Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html says that I can specify a files: attribute.

How can I debug this? I have the following:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/test.txt" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      blah
```

It is in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml and I am running `eb create` in the same directory as the .elasticbeanstalk directory.

And I don't see the file getting created.

Comment: How do you use this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not specified on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html but it should go in .ebextensions/something.config. not in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log and similar files have details about what is going on.